# Monte Carlo policy evaluation confusion

Tags: montecarlo, reinforcement-learning

I'm having trouble understanding Monte Carlo policy evaluation algorithm. What I am reading is that `G` is the average return after visiting a particular state, lets say `s1`, for the first time. Does this mean averaging all rewards following that state `s1` to the end of the episode and then assigning the resulting value to `s1`? Or does it mean the immediate reward received for taking an action in `s1` averaged over multiple episodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of Monte Carlo policy evaluation is to find a value function for a given policy π. A value function for a policy just tells us the expected cumulutive discounted reward that will result from being in a state, then following the policy forever or until the end of the episode. It tells us the *expected return* for a state.

So a Monte Carlo approach to estimating this value function is to simply run the policy and keep track of the return from each state; when I reach a state for the first time, how much discounted reward do I accumulate in the rest of the episode? Average all of these that you observe (one return per each state that you visit, per each episode that you run).

> Does this mean averaging all rewards following that state `s1` to the end of the episode and then assigning the resulting value to `s1`? Or does it mean the immediate reward received for taking an action in `s1` averaged over multiple episodes?

So, your first thought is correct.